# Подскажите как сделать такой cursor эффект при клике со звуком

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, canvas

Недавно на просторах интернета нашел один замечательный [**сайт**](https://geex-arts.com/preview/orsetto-shop) в дизайн и работу фронт-эндера которого я влюбился.

Мне очень понравился там эффект курсора после полной загрузки страницы.

При клике на любом месте страницы создается *звук и wave эффект*.

Как  можно реализовать такое, подскажите пожалуйста? И возможно ли как-то взять данный звук клика с этого сайта. Я облазил их консоль и вкладку `sources` но не нашел ничего.

```js
function playSound () {
    document.getElementById('play').play();
}
```

```html
<audio id="play" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav"></audio>

<button onclick="playSound()">Play</button>
```

Comment: Вы замечаете, что нажатие и отпускание кнопки мыши на этом сайте сопровождается немного разными звуками, хотя очень похожими. Я бы вместо одного события **onclick** применил соответстсвенно два события - **onmousedown** и **onmouseup** с разными звуками. (фрагментами **sounds.mp3**) А  **onclick** вообще звучит в момент отпускания.

Comment: @Олег не один и тот же звук был можете сами посмотреть в аудиозаписей там только один звук клика

Comment: Я на слух обнаружил два звука, они в самом начале файла sounds.mp3 и очень быстро идут один за другим, если слушать всё подряд.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот wave эффект можно сдлеать так.

А звук находится в файле [sounds.mp3](https://geex-arts.com/assets/audio/sounds.mp3).

```js
$(document.body).on('click', function(e) {
  var wave = document.createElement('div');
  wave.style.top = (e.pageY - 25) + "px";
  wave.style.left = (e.pageX - 25) + "px";
  wave.className = 'wave';
  setTimeout(function() {
    wave.classList.add("active");
  }, 0);
  wave.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
    wave.remove();
  });
  document.body.appendChild(wave);
});

$(document.body).on('mouseout', function(e) {
  cursor.style.display = 'none';
});
$(document.body).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  cursor.style.display = 'block';
  cursor.style.top = (e.pageY - 10) + "px";
  cursor.style.left = (e.pageX - 10) + "px";
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

* {
  cursor: none;
}

.wave {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.wave.active {
  transform: scale(3);
  opacity: 0;
}

#cursor {
  background-color: gray;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cursor"></div>
<button>cllck</button>
```

А вообще сайт красивый, но тормозит ужасно.

Comment: Красиво реализовал. Но у меня ничего не  тормозит...  Держи плюс...

Comment: @Air да он прав сайт тормозит дико

Comment: спасибо большое вам также плюсик от меня.но подскажите где вы нашли звук то есть каким образом нашли ?

Comment: @Spectr Я открыл `DevTools`, во вкладке `Network` нашел загруженный звуковой файл. Они грузят его через **AJAX**, поэтому тип у него `XHR`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Озвучку кликов мыши можно реализовать так:

```js
var audio_down = document.getElementById("audio_down");
var audio_up = document.getElementById("audio_up");
audio_down.src = audio_up.src = "https://geex-arts.com/assets/audio/sounds.mp3";
document.onmousedown = function(){mouseSound(0, audio_down)};
document.onmouseup = function(){mouseSound(0.2, audio_up)};
function mouseSound(startCurrentTime, selectedAudio){
 selectedAudio.currentTime = startCurrentTime;
 setTimeout(function(){selectedAudio.pause()}, 200);
 selectedAudio.play();
}
```

```html
Покликайте здесь.
<audio id=audio_down></audio>
<audio id=audio_up></audio>
```

Я сначала хотел сделать всё на одном элементе аудио, но оказалось, что с двумя работает чётче.

Comment: Спасибо +1 от меня отлично

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то я делал wave эффект - после клика на прямоугольном диве от кликнутого места расходятся разноцветные блоки окружностей, а потом они по одному разу отражаются от каждой из "внутренних стен" дива:

```js
var step = 1, // Шаг между окружностями и их толщина. (Можно дробное число, будет интересный эффект.)
num = 50, // Количество окружностей
opacite = 0.3, // Прозрачность окружностей
speed = 50, // Скорость распрастранения окружностей в обратной зависимости
clicked = false,
contayner = document.getElementById("contayner"),
cp = window.getComputedStyle(contayner, null),
w = parseInt(cp.getPropertyValue("width")),
h = parseInt(cp.getPropertyValue("height")),
location_x = parseInt(cp.getPropertyValue("left")),
location_y = parseInt(cp.getPropertyValue("top")),
bw = parseInt(cp.getPropertyValue("border-width"));
for(i = 0; i < num * 5; i++){
 var circle = document.createElement("span");
 circle.id = i;
 contayner.appendChild(circle);
}
contayner.onclick = function(e){
 if(clicked == true){clearInterval(waveInterval)};
 clicked = true;
 var x = e.clientX - location_x - bw;
 var y = e.clientY - location_y - bw;
 var st = 2;
 waveInterval = setInterval (function(){
  for(i=0; i < num; i++){
   var radius = Math.max(st - 1 - i, 0),
   r = 128 + Math.floor(128 * Math.sin(i / 3 + st / 15)),
   g = 128 + Math.floor(128 * Math.sin(i / 5 - st / 15)),
   b = 128 + Math.floor(128 * Math.sin(i / 7 + st / 25)),
   mas = [[x, -x, w * 2 - x, x, x], [y, y, y, -y, h * 2 - y]];
   for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    var c = document.getElementById(i + j * num);
    c.style = "border-radius: " + radius * step + "px;" +
     "border-style: solid;" +
     "border-width: " + step + "px;" +
     "border-color: rgba(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ", " + opacite + ")";
    c.style.position = "absolute";
    c.style.width = c.style.height = radius * step * 2 + "px";
    c.style.left = mas[0][j] - radius * step + "px";
    c.style.top = mas[1][j] - radius * step + "px";
   }
  }
  st++;
  if(st > 1000){
   clearInterval(waveInterval);
   clicked = false;
  }
 }, speed);
}
```

```css
#contayner{
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-style: solid;
 width: 300px;
 height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id=contayner> Кликните здесь.</div>
```

После любого изменения значений первых четырёх JS-переменных (на против которых есть комментарии) можно получить новые спец-эффекты. Пока что, после каждого нового клика все предыдущие круги исчезают.

Comment: скучный эффект очень медленно все происходит.Но ответ не стирайте потом посмотрю ваш код анализирую постараюсь понять что к чему

Comment: Увеличив переменную step можно сделать быстрее.